# How to disable Jquery prompt save button on first click

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, impromptu

I am using jQuery prompt to prompt a user to save.  So, a user clicks a Save button,  the Jquery prompt displays and asks if the user is sure he/she wants to save changes or not.  The problem is, the user is able to click multiple times on the jQuery Save prompt button before the prompt closes.  As a result, my save routine runs once for each time the prompt save button is clicked, which results in duplicate records in the database.  I need to disable the prompt save button on the first click or simply close the prompt window on the first click to prevent multiple saves.  How can I do this?

Client code:

```
$.prompt("Are you sure you want to save? You will not be able to change your decision after it's been saved.", {
    title: "Save?",
    buttons: { "Save": true, "Cancel": false },
    submit: function (e, v, m, f) {
        if (v) {
            response = saveUpdates(LoanDetails);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: You might want to remove the knockout.js tag since it is not used anywhere in this code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/smurphy/4fqjR/

The solution is a little convoluted. I thought there would be a simpler way to do it but after looking through the [documentation](http://www.shiguenori.com/material/jquery.impromptu/) I cannot find any built in feature.

Here is the code:

```
submit: function (value, message) {
        if (value) {
            $(message.prevObject)
               .find('button[value="true"]')
               .attr('disabled', true);

            //TODO: perform save 
            //response = saveUpdates(LoanDetails);
        }
    }
```

The `message` param is a reference to the text description so you can find the button by navigating around the DOM from that starting point.

Comment: I did have that, but it does not impact the save button on the jQuery prompt, only the input (it does disable the input, not the jQuery prompt button).

Comment: Oh! misunderstood your question.

Comment: Updated question to target the prompt save button

Comment: Thanks Scott, but it still did not work.  Can't be this difficult.

Comment: Ok I created a fiddle to debug and figure out what params are actually passed to the submit function. This should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a global variable as a flag, 
or disable the prompt button (if you are using a button to call the prompt)
$("#promptbutton").prop("disabled",true);

Edit:

The easier solution is to simply close the prompt right before calling the saveUpdates function, or at the start of the function:

```
jQuery.prompt.close();
```

Comment: This is better suited as a comment since it does not provide an answer to the OP's question. BTW, if you click on the tags in the questions they may lead you to the plugin. :)

Comment: Oh sorry, I didn't noticed the tag leading to the plugin, I will edit my answer. Thanks

Comment: @JayBlanchard, what is Trader supposed to do since he doesn't have enough rep to add comments?

Comment: Honestly @ScottMurphy he is supposed to do enough to earn enough rep to post comments. It has been discussed ad nauseum on http://meta.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: i tried putting jQuery.prompt.close(); inside the if (v) but did not work.